# UI Element that takes focus and doesn't allow other interactions

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to make a pop-up that grabs focus and doesn't allow the user to click on any other part of the app. I also want it to be an instance of Page so I can modify it. Any suggestions? -Couldn't think of a better example but take this one per se [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. I looked here and there and this is what I found:

You can make use of a pop-up control. If you want to make sure it doesn't allow any other attention set [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.islightdismissenabled?view=winrt-19041) to false :